# Socket programming: sendto always fails with errno 22 (EINVAL)

Tags: c, sockets, udp, sendto

I am always getting no bytes sent, with an errno of 22 (EINVAL, Invalid Argument) with this code.  The `destination_host` is set elsewhere and known to be valid, so I really don't see what is going on.  `MAXMSGSIZE` is 1000.  No errors, or warnings.  I am compiling with `-Wall -Werror -pedantic`

```
char *data_rec;
u_int data_len;

int sockfd;
uint16_t *ns;
struct sockaddr_in address;
struct sockaddr *addr;

char *ip;

int i;
int errno;
int bytes_sent;

data_len = MAXMSGSIZE;
data_rec = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAXMSGSIZE);
ns = malloc(MAXMSGSIZE*sizeof(uint16_t));
ip = malloc(MAXMSGSIZE*sizeof(char));

data_rec = "some random test stuff";

sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if(sockfd<0) {
    printf("socket() failed\n");
}

inet_ntop(AF_INET,destination_host->h_addr,ip,MAXMSGSIZE);
memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(theirPort);
address.sin_addr.s_addr = (unsigned long)ip;

addr = (struct sockaddr*)&address;
bind(sockfd,addr,sizeof(address));
/*Convert the message to uint16_t*/
for(i=0; i<MAXMSGSIZE; i++) {
    ns[i] = htons(data_rec[i]);
}


/* send the message */
bytes_sent = sendto(sockfd, ns, data_len, MSG_DONTWAIT, addr, sizeof(addr));
if(bytes_sent == -1) {
    printf("Error sending: %i\n",errno);
}
```

Comment: You could use `perror()` to get a more descriptive error message than `errno 22`

Comment: What happens when s_addr is INADDR_ANY? If that works, you know the problem is... :-)

Comment: Also, it seems that you declare `errno` and never assign to it. Maybe you wanted to write `extern int errno`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're giving the wrong size for the address. `addr` is really a `struct sockaddr_in`, not a `struct sockaddr`.

Change the last parameter of sendto to `sizeof(address)`

Comment: Odd how this worked.  An example I was following used the size of the sockaddr_in struct and worked fine.

Answer (score 5):

`inet_ntop` probably isn't what you want - it converts from **network** (i.e. wire) format into **presentation** format (i.e. "1.2.3.4"). Try:

```
address.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long *)destination_host->h_addr);
```

Comment: In fairness, nos's answer is more likely to fix the error you're seeing, but my answer explains your next problem: why the receiver isn't seeing anything :)

Answer (score -1):

You have:

```
bytes_sent = sendto(sockfd, ns, data_len, MSG_DONTWAIT, addr, sizeof(addr));
```

Because `sizeof(addr) == 4` (or 8), use `sizeof(*addr)`.

Comment: It needs to be `sizeof(address)`, doesn't it?  And that's what the accepted answer says.  The trouble with `sizeof(*addr)` is that it is `sizeof(struct sockaddr)`, but the variable is actually a `struct sockaddr_in`.  The sockets interface is pretty peculiar, especially the way it handles different types and sizes of addresses.