# Sockets sendto() returning EINVAL

Tags: c, sockets, udp, ipv4, sendto

I'm trying to send a UDP packet in C. I have the following `sendto()`:

```
char* msg = "Hello";

//ret is the return value of getaddrinfo, the address is AF_INET (IPv4)
//and the sock_type is SOCK_DGRAM (UDP)
struct sockaddr_in *ip = (struct sockaddr_in *)ret->ai_addr;

if ((sendto(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr *)ip, 
                sizeof(struct sockaddr *))) != -1) {
    printf("msg sent successfully");
} else {
    printf("Error sending msg: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

However, it's returning an error saying there's an invalid argument. Looking at the manpage I can't really tell which one is the invalid argument. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's all my code

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    /*
     * Help the technically challenged among us who have no idea
     * what on God's green Earth they are doing with this thing.
    */
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: routetracer <ip address or hostname>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /*
     * hints- parameters for return value of getaddrinfo
     * ret- return value of getaddrinfo
     */
    struct addrinfo hints, *ret;
    int status;
    char ipv4[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int ttl = 0;
    char* msg = "Hello";
    int last_hop = 0;

    //define what we want from getaddrinfo
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; //IPv4
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; //UDP packets

    //call getaddrinfo to fill ret, w/ error chk
    if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], NULL, &hints, &ret)) != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        return -1;
    }

    //extract IPv4 address from ret
    struct sockaddr_in* ip = (struct sockaddr_in *)ret->ai_addr;

    //convert address from pure numbers to something easier to read
    inet_ntop(ret->ai_family, &(ip->sin_addr), ipv4, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);   

    //kindly inform the user of which hostname they are connecting to
    printf("Route for: %s\n", ipv4);

    //create a socket
    int sock = socket(ret->ai_family, ret->ai_socktype, ret->ai_protocol);

    ttl = 1;
    if ((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl))) != -1) {
        printf("TTL set successfully\n");
    } else {
        printf("Error setting TTL: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    if ((sendto(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0, ret->ai_addr,
                    ret->ai_addrlen)) != -1) {
        printf("msg sent successfully");
    } else {
      printf("Error sending msg: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running the program gives the following output:

```
$ ./routetracer www.google.com
Route for: 173.194.46.82
TTL set successfully
Error sending msg: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Barmar points out, *one* reason for the `EINVAL` is the incorrect:

```
  sizeof(struct sockaddr *)
```

which gives the size of a pointer. See [Socket programming: sendto always fails with errno 22 (EINVAL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006786/socket-programming-sendto-always-fails-with-errno-22).

The *second* reason seems to be `sin_port`, which `getaddrinfo` returns as `0`. Changing it to `80` say clears up the `EINVAL`, as in:

```
  ((struct sockaddr_in *)ret->ai_addr)->sin_port = htons(80); // test
```

Here port 80 here is not HTTP, but instead (for UDP) is Google's experimental QUIC Chromium.

Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers states that Port 0 is for UDP ***reserved***, and for TCP  is unofficially reserved as a "programming technique for specifying system-allocated (dynamic) ports".

And as an aside (and referring to the original question), you may not need bother with the variable `ip`. You are casting `ret->ai_addr` to `struct sockaddr_in *`, and then *back again* to its original type.

And, as Remy Lebeau points out, it is better to use the `service` parameter of `getaddrinfo`. So putting this all together, your code could look more like:

```
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET; //IPv4
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM; //UDP packets
  if ((status = getaddrinfo(argv[1], "80", &hints, &ret)) != 0) {
      printf("getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
      return -1;
  }
  assert(ret->ai_family   == AF_INET);     // guaranteed
  assert(ret->ai_socktype == SOCK_DGRAM);  // guaranteed
  assert(((struct sockaddr_in *)ret->ai_addr)->sin_port == htons(80)); // guaranteed
  // ...
  if ((sendto(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0, ret->ai_addr, ret->ai_addrlen)) != -1) {
  // ...
```

Comment: I have ip because I need a `struct sockaddr_in*` for a call to `inet_ntop()`. However, I used your suggestion, and it still gives me the same error. I'm going to edit my original post with all my code thus far (including your suggestion).

Comment: @Hugo: I have been away. Thank you for your complete code. The problem was easily duplicated. Hopefully this new suggestion helps.

Comment: You need to use `htons()` when assigning the `sin_port` value.

Comment: You can pass an optional port number/service in the `service` parameter of `getaddrinfo()`, then `sin_port` will be initialized for you.

Comment: Finally thank you so much. I just used the service parameter of getaddrinfo as Remy Lebeau suggested. It seemed like a simpler solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
if ((sendto(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr *)ip, 
                sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) != -1) {
```

You're giving it the size of a pointer, not the size of the structure. And it needs to be the specific structure type, not the generic type.