# C Networking: Sendto() returning Errno 22, EINVAL

Tags: c, sockets, networking, arguments, sendto

I'm attempting to generate a packet from scratch with Layer 2, 3, and 4 components (namely Ethernet, IP, and UDP). My socket is configured to use SOCK_RAW as the type and IPPROTO_RAW as the protocol, so that my program can be used to send different protocols at a later date. I've strictly abided by the sendto(2) man page (https://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto), however, I still seem to be having troubles transmitting a packet over local host. The error returned by my program is 22, or EINVAL, indicating that I've passed an incorrect argument.

I've already used [Sockets sendto() returning EINVAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977839/sockets-sendto-returning-einval) and [Socket programming: sendto always fails with errno 22 (EINVAL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006786/socket-programming-sendto-always-fails-with-errno-22-einval) in attempt to resolve my problem. I've even switched the socket to use SOCK_DGRAM as the type and IPPROTO_UDP as the protocol to see if it was something to do with the socket (though I don't believe this would have prompted an incorrect argument response).

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        /* Socket Creation */
    int sockfd;

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) == -1) {
            perror("Socket");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // This will hold all of the packet's contents
    char sendbuf[BUFFER];


    /* Address Stuff */

    // Specify Address
    in_addr_t address = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    // Specifying Address for Sendto()
    struct sockaddr_in sendto_addr;
    memset(&sendto_addr, 0, sizeof(sendto_addr));
    sendto_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sendto_addr.sin_port = htons(9623);  // Make sure the port isn't contested
    sendto_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = address;

    // Size of whole packet
    size_t total_len = 0;


    /* LAYER 2 */
    // Ethernet Header Configuration
    struct ether_header *ether = (struct ether_header *)sendbuf;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        ether -> ether_dhost[i] = 0x00; // Temporary data fill
        ether -> ether_shost[i] = 0x00; // Temporary data fill
    }
    ether -> ether_type = ETHERTYPE_IP;

    total_len += sizeof(struct ether_header);


    /* LAYER 3 */
    // IP Header Configuration
    struct ip *ip = (struct ip *)(sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header));

    ip -> ip_hl = 5;
    ip -> ip_v = 4;
    ip -> ip_tos = 0;
    ip -> ip_p = 17;
    ip -> ip_ttl = 255;
    ip -> ip_src.s_addr = address;
    ip -> ip_dst.s_addr = address;  

    total_len += sizeof(struct ip); 


    /* LAYER 4 */
    // UDP Header Configuration
    struct udphdr *udp = (struct udphdr *)(sendbuf + sizeof(struct ether_header) + \
                                           sizeof(struct ip));

    udp -> source = 123; // Gibberish to fill in later
    udp -> dest = 321;   // Gibberish to fill in later
    udp -> check = 0;

    total_len += sizeof(struct udphdr);


    /* Giberrish Packet Data */
    sendbuf[total_len++] = 0x00;
    sendbuf[total_len++] = 0x00;
    sendbuf[total_len++] = 0x00;
    sendbuf[total_len++] = 0x00;


    /* Fill in Rest of Headers */
    udp -> len = htons(total_len - sizeof(struct ether_header) - sizeof(struct ip));
    ip -> ip_len = htons(total_len - sizeof(struct ether_header));


    /* Send Packet */  // ERROR OCCURS HERE
    printf("Sockfd is %d\n", sockfd);
    printf("Total length is %d\n", total_len);
    if (sendto(sockfd, sendbuf, total_len, 0, (const struct sockaddr*)&sendto_addr, \
        sizeof(sendto_addr)) < 0) {
            printf("Error sending packet: Error %d.\n", errno);
            perror("sendto Error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    close(sockfd);

}
```

The precise console message states:

> Sockfd is 3
>       Total length is 46
>       Error sending packet: Error 22.
>       sendto Error: Invalid argument

Comment: What OS / kernel are you running? Also `#define BUFFER 65535` and `char sendbuf[BUFFER];` - that's 65 KiB of memory, that's a lot. Usually OSes don't allow more then 4Kb to be allocated on stack.

Comment: @KamilCuk OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux v. 7.6 //  
Kernel: 3.10.0-957.12.1.el7.x86_64 //  
I've lowered it to 1024, thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka! It was actually this line:

```
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) == -1) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Which should have been

```
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Why this fixed the problem? Great question, would love to see someone's response on the subject :P